# Google Sheets: Fill range with value if cell is edited using AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am trying to fill a Range in my Spreadsheet dynamically on Edit.
If a value is entered in column A then all cells in the same row should be filled with the word "Default"

Here's my code

```html
const onEdit = (e) => {
  var currentRow = e.range.getRowIndex();
  var currentSheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().geName();
  var currentSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if(currentRow > 1){
  if(currentSheetName === "EingabeSheet"){
currentSheet.getRange("B"+currentRow.toString()+":R"+currentRow.toString()).setValue("Default");
  }
}
}
```

Unfortunately it does nothing when I enter a value in column A.

Any help is appreciated,
Jan

Comment: Shouldn't it be `getName()`?

Comment: yes it should and now it works :D thank you so much